# How to use animated material ui icons in React

Tags: reactjs, animation, icons, material-ui

https://material.io/design/iconography/animated-icons.html
I attached link above how can i integrated icon in my react application there is not have any code.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not supported out of the box by material-ui, but you can use css transitions to accomplish it.

Maybe this lib can solve it for you or at least inspire your implementation?

https://mui.wertarbyte.com/#material-ui-toggle-icon

Their implementation looks pretty nice, well documented and MIT: https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-toggle-icon

Answer (score -2):

Google Material does not provide an implementation of their icons with animations. [They do; however, provide a specification/guideline for animation with Material Icons.](https://material.io/design/iconography/animated-icons.html)

In addition; you can download the SVG Icons here as needed: https://material.io/tools/icons/ 
and import into your code.

Comment: I don't see anything about animation in that link

Comment: Google material doesn't provide the implementation of the animation, just the specification/guideline.